# Setting Accent Color on Xamarin.Mac Big Sur

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-mac, macos-big-sur, xamarin.mac

In macOS Big Sur you can set an accent color of the app. In XCode you can do that by changing the color in the Assets catalog.

After a lot of research this does not appear to be possible in Xamarin. However it seems that there is a possible workaround which is vaguely documented: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10275#issuecomment-855436269

Did someone manage to use this workaround or knows how to actually do something based on this description?